AES Encryption and \decryption in android
I have a sign in API in which API provide a secret key in decrypt form like below to further used in different types of APIs for data fetching. I have to decrypt it for use case.
"secretAccessKey": { "ciphertext": { "words": [ -11211163938, 15677252277, 14825332397, 8644425824, 5827551513, -14516662867, 10680784880, 9296565512, 435337374, 2609999864, -19100081560, 453333329 ], "sigBytes": 48 }, "key": { "words": [ 15778663618, 14227885834, 18916051559, 14199998468, 16285585456, 16313393861, 20211151033, 20513332385, -16025004046, -1008020031, 8954886893, 5647776294 ], "sigBytes": 32 }, "iv": { "words": [ -16025454446, -1008737731, 8954444593, 5644223294 ], "sigBytes": 16 }, "salt": { "words": [ -7514324436, 9903098141 ], "sigBytes": 8 }, "blockSize": 4 },
I have tried below decryptor class available on internet but did not get correct result.
public class Decryptor {

    public ResponseData parseResponseData(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, ResponseData.class);
    }

    public String decrypt(EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys) throws Exception {
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = intArrayToByteArray(encryptionKeys.ciphertext.words);
        byte[] keyBytes = intArrayToByteArray(encryptionKeys.key.words);
        byte[] ivBytes = intArrayToByteArray(encryptionKeys.iv.words);

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);
        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }

    private byte[] intArrayToByteArray(int[] intArray) {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[intArray.length * 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i * 4] = (byte) ((intArray[i] >> 24) & 0xFF);
            byteArray[i * 4 + 1] = (byte) ((intArray[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
            byteArray[i * 4 + 2] = (byte) ((intArray[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
            byteArray[i * 4 + 3] = (byte) (intArray[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}

Any body give me a direction how to work on this.

You need to get the code for encryption. Trying to guess all the missing details may eventually succeed but there's no reason to do so.

Could be a CipherParams object, as used by CryptoJS. However, the associated word array of key is 48 bytes in size (12 words a 4 bytes), whereas it should actually be 32 bytes, as indicated by the associated sigBytes. Is the data correct/consistent?

@Topaco you guess right. actually on web, our team used crypto-ts and now i have to use it in android app. i have change some data. can you guide me how to do this?

In order for the Java code to decrypt a default CryptoJS encryption with AES, intArrayToByteArray[] must be adapted. This is incomplete, as only words, but not sigBytes, is taken into account. Not all bytes resulting from words may be used, but only the first sigBytes bytes (keep in mind: 1 word = 4 bytes). In addition, new String(decryptedBytes) only makes sense if the data is a string for sure, otherwise the data should be returned as binary (or converted to a string using a binary-to-text encoding as Base64 or hex).

However, it is unclear whether these adjustments are sufficient to decrypt your data, as the information you posted does not say anything about whether the data was actually generated with a default CryptoJS encryption with AES. To check this, at least the plaintext of the posted test data is required, or even better the encryption code.
